# Use static variables in a RestController in a SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot 2.0.5.RELEASE project with some Rest Controllers.

in my of the controller I have this method:

```
GetMapping(path = "/menu", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<List<String>> menus() {

            List<String> result = Arrays.stream(MenuAlertEnum.values())
                      .map(MenuAlertEnum::getAlertName)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return ResponseEntity.ok(result);

        }
```

Since MenuAlertEnum are app. constants and will have always the same values I want to put it as a static variable in the controller to make it faster, but By default, a spring bean is a singleton I think is not a good practice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Static Block of Java to initialize the value. It just run once.

```
static List<String> alertNames;

static {
  alertNames = Arrays.stream(MenuAlertEnum.values())
                      .map(MenuAlertEnum::getAlertName)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And then use alertNames in your controller directly.

Comment: Better to even have `MenuAlertEnum` return the `Stream`/`List` via a static method.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no issues accessing static data from a singleton bean, beyond any normal concurrency concerns.

If you prefer not to use static variables, you could use `@PostConstruct` in your controller to initialize a local variable instead:

```
private List<String> alerts;
....
@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
    alerts = Arrays.stream(MenuAlertEnum.values())
                  .map(MenuAlertEnum::getAlertName)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java `Enum` was created to avoid using `public static final String CONSTATNT_VALUE = "FOO"`. You can call enums anywhere from a static context, so there is no need to create any static blocks.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/menu", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public List<MenuAlertEnum> menus() {
    return Arrays.asList(MenuAlertEnum.values());
}
```

- only static `Arrays.asList()` and static `MenuAlertEnum.values()` - easy to read and only one line of code. Hope you'll find it useful :)